# How to verify that we can define a group operation by putting $a \star b = \phi ^{-1}(\phi (a) \phi (b))$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> let $E$ be a set, and $(G, \cdot)$ a group. We suppose that there exists a bijection $\phi : E \rightarrow G$. Show that we can define a law of a group $\star$ on E by:
>   $$\forall a \in E, \forall b \in E, a \star b = \phi ^{-1}(\phi (a) \phi (b)) $$

So basically, I figure I have to show that $(E,\star)$ be a group.

My attempt:

- **Associativity:** let $a,b,c \in E$, then $$
  \begin{align}
   (a \star b) \star c &= \phi ^{-1}(\phi (a \star b) \phi (c))\\
  &= \phi^{-1}(\phi (\phi ^{-1}(\phi (a)\phi(b)) \phi(c))\\
  & = \phi^{-1}(\phi(a) \phi(b) \phi(c))
  \end{align}$$
  and 
  $$\begin{align}
  a \star (b \star c) &= \phi ^{-1}(\phi (a) \phi (b \star c)) \\
  &= \phi ^{-1} (\phi(a)\phi (\phi^{-1}(\phi(a)\phi(b)))) \\
  &= \phi^{-1}(\phi(a)\phi(b)\phi(c)).
  \end{align}$$
- **Closure:** if $a, b \in E$ then $a \star b \in E$. As $a\star b = \phi ^{-1}(\phi(a) \phi(b))$ and $\phi (a) \in G$, $\phi (b) \in G$ and as G is a group, then $\phi(a) \phi(b) \in G$, thus $\phi ^{-1} (\phi(a) \phi(b)) \in E$
- **Identity element:** Let $e \in G$ be the identity element of $G$, and let's prove that $\phi ^{-1}(e)$ is the identity element of $E$. We have $\forall a \in G$, $a \star \phi ^{-1}(e)= \phi ^{-1}(\phi (a) \phi (\phi ^{-1}(e)))= \phi ^{-1}(\phi(a) e)=\phi ^{-1}(\phi (a))=a$. Similar proofs goes in showing $\phi^{-1}(e) \star a =a$
- **Inverse element:** For $a\in G$, then inverse would be the inverse of $\phi (a)$ in $G$, which well denote as $phi(x)$. Proof: $a\star x = \phi^{-1}(\phi (a) \phi(x') )= \phi^{-1}(e)$. Same goes for $x \star a$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Your proof is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is correct.

As is customary for a [proof-verification](/questions/tagged/proof-verification) question, I am required to elaborate on my answer with some feedback on the proposed proof. As such, I will commend you on your decision to split the associativity proof in half, since, otherwise, it would be a sea of symbols to most readers.